# Access 2010 keeps opening as 2007. Can't reference correct object library

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, libraries

Can't create an Excel 2010 spreadsheet in Access 2007.

I'm an experienced Access VBA programmer. I'm trying to create an Excel spreadsheet from Access, which I've done a dozen times before, but I keep getting an error saying my libraries aren't included.

Here's the crux. The Office suite is 2010. Excel and Word open as 2010. Access start bar entry point says 2010 too, but when I open it, Access opens as 2007.

I can Dim an Excel application as a New, but when I try to Set it, error (incorrect library).

I can Dim an Excel application by CreateObject(). This allows me to Set it but my first command (visible = true) sets of the same error.

My object libraries are version .14 (2010) so I guess Excel would be happy. But Access 2007 wants object library .12, hence my error. Object libraries .12 aren't in my list of references.

I'm working on database in a Cambodian village for a charity school so there is now way I can reinstall the 2010 Office suite.

I've been all through the registry and can only find CurVer set to .14. I've registered msadox.dll. That's fine.

I see two solutions...

1. How do I stop my Access 2010 from opening as 2007.
2. How do I get my object libraries .12 to list in my references along side my object libraries .14.

Here's my code...

```vb
Private Sub Command_Create_Click()
    Dim app As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Set app = New Excel.Application
    app.Visible = True
    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Add
    wb.Activate
    Set wks = wb.ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

The code falls over at `Set app` with Run-time error '-2147319779 (8002801d)': Automation error Library not registered.

Any help appreciated. Please remember I'm working in a third world village and many options (reinstall, download, setup) are unavailable to me without travelling to the nearest city.

Comment: Please provide a full code block including all `Dim` and `Set` lines not in text that raises the error, so we can better follow as a [mcve]. Also, post the references you have checked under `Tools\References`. Be sure to always `Debug\Compile` after making coding changes. This can even capture incorrect library references.

Comment: If you go full late bindings (so `Dim excelApp As Object` and then `CreateObject(...` references should not matter, so you should not get incorrect library errors.

Comment: RE "Access opens as 2007", what does this show you in the Immediate window? `Debug.Print SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessDir)`

Comment: Hansup,

    To be honest I've never used the debugging tools. I've just used MsgBox. It's done me fine.

      However, I've had a good look at the debugging tools, breakpoints and immediate windows (which I have used, professionally, with other languages). Perhaps, if I used it habitually in VBA, I'd debug quicker. I think I should.

      SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessDir) = C:\Program Files (x86) \Microsoft Office\Office14\

The Office Suite is 2010. The Access directory is Office14 (2010) yet Access opens up with the window heading saying ": Database (Access 2007)"

Arrgh!!!

Comment: Parfait,

     Here's my code...

Private Sub Command_Create_Click()

      Dim app As Excel.Application
      Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
      Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet

      Set app = New Excel.Application
      app.Visible = True

      Set wb = app.Workbooks.Add
      wb.Activate

      Set wks = wb.ActiveSheet

End Sub

Falls over when setting app... 

Run-time error '-2147319779 (8002801d)':

Automation error
Library not registered. 

     I've never used Debug\Compile Database before. I tried with no response. I figure there's no compilation error.

Comment: Erik A,
I've never gone late binding before I had this current problem. When I gave the Excell.Applucation a command (visible = True) it fell over with the usual error. I'll try to late bind everything.
    ..... 

     Dim app As Object
     Dim wb As Object
     Dim wks As Object

     Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
     Set wb = app.Workbooks.Add
     wb.Activate
     Set wks = wb.ActiveSheet
    ...
     It falls over when setting wb, telling me a library is missing. Breakpoint hover 'app' = "Nothing". Set app doesn't trigger an error.